# Java Application started via Windows Task Scheduler not visible in VisualVM

Tags: jvm, windows-task-scheduler, visualvm

When starting a JakartaEE application (Payara 6 on JDK 11) via Windows Server Task Scheduler, the process starts fine and with the correct user but is not visible in VisualVM.

After running the same command (batch file) manually, the process is visible in VisualVM.

What are the differences between running the batch file manually and running it from task scheduler? Is there a way to make the process visible to VisualVM?

ChatGPT suggested looking into User Context and Session Isolation but I could not make it work.

Comment: Is the JVM running VisualVM and the same as the the one running the scheduled JVM?    I believe they look for PID files in the same JVM directory.

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo the JVMs are different, but that should not be a problem. VisualVM shows processes of (at least) 5 different JVM installation directories.